# How can I set in a form ID from url?

Tags: asp.net

I have page with film details, for example link: http://yyy.yy/Pages/Film/Details.aspx?filmId=5 and user can add on this page comment from some film, for example film with filmId = 5. But after click Save button in method InsertComment() after TryUpdateModel() FilmId from form = 0 and it should be = for example 5 - how can I do that?

This is mine code:

        
            
                
                    ' Enabled="False">

```
                <div class="editor-label">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Author"></asp:Label>
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" Text='<%# Bind("Author") %>' runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>

                <div class="editor-label">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Content"></asp:Label>
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="500" Height="200" Text='<%# Bind("Content") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
                <br />

                <p class="alignright">
                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Save" CommandName="Insert" />
                </p>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </InsertItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
```

---

```
namespace Project.Pages.Film
{
    public partial class Index : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        public void InsertComment()
        {
            var item = new Comments();

            TryUpdateModel(item);  //item.FilmId = 0 and it should be = for example 5
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                .........
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the rest of your form code in? FilmId needs to be an input on the page somewhere

Comment: If you are in PostBack mode, you can just get the film Id from Request.QueryString["filmId"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
public partial class Index : System.Web.UI.Page
{

  int FilmID { get; set; }

  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    FilmID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["filmId"]);
  }

  public void InsertComment()
  {
    var item = new Comments();
    item.FilmID  = FilmID;
    TryUpdateModel(item);  //item.FilmId = 0 and it should be = for example 5
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        .........
    }
  }
}
```